# c++ what is a good debugger for segmentation errors?

Tags: c++, debugging

Does anyone know a good debugger for C++ segmentation errors on the Linux environment? It would be good enough if the debugger could trace which function is causing the error.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `gdb` the *only* debugger available on that platform?

Comment: I haven't used gdb before is there a good tutorial on that?

Comment: @Mark: It's kind of opaque because it's a command line only debugger. YMMV.

Comment: @Mark: On another note, `valgrind` is not a debugger, and won't let you step through code, but it will tell you where segmentation faults lie.

Comment: How detail does it tell me? does it tell which line of code?

Comment: @Mark: It will tell you on which line the fault occurs, yes. It won't let you see what led up to it though.

Comment: what about gdb? Does that work well for segmentation faults?

Comment: @Mark: Not sure, I've never seriously used it. I know something of what it's capable, but I don't have too much experience with it's use.

Comment: @Mark: `valgrind` is a tool can tell you the possible memory corruptions and memory leaks your program has, `gdb` is a debugger which helps you `debug` your program, step through each statement by statement and find out where the problem lies.

Comment: @Billy:  For x86 there is also the [Intel debugger](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/idb-linux/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB! what else is available on Linux?

Check [**this**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/) out for starting up with GDB, its a nice, concise and easy to understand tutorial.

Comment: @Mark: GDB was designed for C in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider some techniques that do require from you code changes:

1. Run your app via ***valgrind*** memcheck tool. It's possible to catch error when you access wrong address (e.g. freed pointer, not initialized) - see [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.badrw).
2. If you use extensievly *stl/boost*, consider compiling with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG and -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC (see [here](http://linuxjunk.blogspot.com/2009/10/vector-bounds-checking-in-gcc.html)). This can catch such errors as using invalidated iterator, accessing incorrect index in vector etc.
3. ***tcmalloc*** (from [google per tool](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/)). When linking with it's debug enabled version, it may find memory related problems
4. Even [more](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html) ...

Comment: +1 valgrind is probably more useful than a debugger for finding a seg fault

Answer (score 2):

GDB is indeed about the only choice. There are some GUI's but they are allmost all wrappers for gdb. Finding a segfault is easy. Make sure you compile with -g -O0 then start gdb with your program as argument.

In gdb type run

To start your program running, gdb will stop it is soon as it hits a segfault and report on which line that was. If you need a full backtrace then just type bt. To get out of gdb enter quit.

BTW gdb has a build in help, just type help.

Comment: A word of caution, some tricky segfault issues will disappear if you normally compile with optimizations, but switch to -O0 for debugging.  You can debug with higher -O flags but it's harder.